# Saving values set in Frontend to Django Database

Tags: django, database, model-view-controller, orm, django-views

I have a website which allows Users to pick a few hobbies they enjoy. Currently the website loads these hobbies from a Model and lists them with a Checkbox. What I want to do is when a User saves the form, it should also save these Checkbox values to the database - i.e if they tick Football, the database should save the fact that this User enjoys football. I am new to Django and Python so not too sure how to accomplish this. Here is the code I am using. This is the Models.py file for the Hobbies:

```
TYPES = (
        ("Football", "Football"),
        ("Cricket", "Cricket"),
        ("Swimming", "Swimming"),
        ("Cycling", "Cycling")
        )

class Hobby(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = TYPES, default=TYPES[0], null=True)
    football = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    cricket = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    swimming = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    cycling = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

This is the relevant views.py file:

```
def profile(request, user):
    # use this for debugging:
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if 'email' in request.POST:
        email = request.POST['email']
        gender = request.POST['gender']
        dob = request.POST['dob']
##        hobby = request.POST['hobby']
        if user.profile:
            user.profile.email = email
            user.profile.gender = gender
            user.profile.dob = dob
##            user.profile.hobby = hobby
            user.profile.save()
        else:
            profile = Profile(email=email, gender=gender, dob=dob)
            profile.save()
            user.profile = profile
        user.save()
    context = {
        'appname': appname,
        'username': user.username,
        'profile' : user.profile,
        'all_hobbies': [hobby[0] for hobby in TYPES],
        'loggedin': True
    }
    return render(request, 'mainapp/profile.html', context)
```

And lastly the HTML/JS code to display the information:

```
<span class="fieldname">Hobbies</span>
        {% for hobby in all_hobbies %}

                <input type="checkbox" name={{hobby}} value={{hobby}}> {{hobby}}<br>
        {% endfor %}

<input type='submit' value='Save'>
```

What I want is a way to check whether the checkboxes have been ticked, and if so to change the value of the BooleanField in the database/model to either True or False. However, I am not sure where to do this, in the views or the JS code. Can someone help me out here? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this case to list all hobbies and update them again. You need to use a Form Class. Example. I just want to mention a single thing, the code below its just a guideline of what you should do. Because Its kind of confusing the logic you want to approach. Since you are not handleing a user as a session but just a plain key.

## model.py

```
my_choices = (
    (0, "None"),
    (1, "Football"),
    (2, "Cricket"),
    (3, "Swimming"),
    (4, "Cycling"),
)
class Hobby(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    field = models.integerField(choices=my_choices, default=0)
```

## forms.py

```
class HobbyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hobby
        fields = ["field"]
```

## views.py

```
def profile(request,user):

    try:
        profile_object = Profile.get(id=user)

        if request.method.POST:
            form = HobbyForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                profile_object.field = form.cleaned_data["field"]
                profile_object.save()

                context = {
                        "form": form,
                        "profile": profile_object,
                    }
                return render(request, 'mainapp/profile.html', context)

            else:
                context = {
                        "form": form,
                        "profile": profile_object,
                    }
                return render(request, 'mainapp/profile.html', context)
        else:
            context = {
                        "form": form,
                        "profile": profile_object,
                    }
            return render(request, 'mainapp/profile.html', context)

    except Profile.DoesNotExists:
        context = {
            "form": form,
            "profile": profile_object,
        }
        return render(request, 'mainapp/profile.html', context)
```

## profile.html

```
<form action="myurl/{{profile.id}}/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% form.as_p %}
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```